# $(\text{Im}(T^*))^0 = \ker(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> **Definitions:** Let $V$ be a vector space and $M\subseteq V$ subspace. We define $V^* :=$ space of all linear transformations $f:V\to \mathbb{F}$ and  $M^0:=\{f\in V^*| f(M)=0\}$.

In a class of (advanced) linear algebra my professor proposed, as exercise, to prove these two equalities: $$\ker(T^*) = (\text{Im}(T))^0,$$ and $$(\text{Im}(T^*))^0 = \ker(T),$$ for a linear function $T:V\to W.$ I'm OK with the first (I wrote it here to show that confusing both equalities is not the case). But the second I don't see how it can be true, once $\text{Im}(T^*)\subseteq V^*$ so $(\text{Im}(T^*))^0 \subseteq V^{**} := (V^*)^* $ and $\ker(T)\subseteq V$. Just wanted some confirmation if the equality is not (always) true.

Comment: Recall that for finite dimensional vector spaces $V^{**}$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$. Your concern might not be justified.

Comment: $\text{Im}(T^*)\subseteq V^*$ so $(\text{Im}(T^*))^0 \subseteq V^{**}$... how?

Comment: It's a common (slight) abuse of notation. For a subspace $F$ of $V^{\ast}$, let $F^0 = \{ x \in V : f(x) = 0 \text{ for all } f \in F\}$. It would be more clean to denote that e.g. $^0F$ to avoid confusion with the annihilator of $F$ in $V^{\ast\ast}$, but it's rarely done.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I edited with definitions

Comment: @Mathematician42 but how I "organize" the isomorphism and the sets so that I can say they're "equal"?

Comment: You can always view $V\subset V^{**}$ using the map $V\rightarrow V^{**}:v\mapsto \text{ev}_v$. Here $\text{ev}_v:V^*\rightarrow k: \phi\mapsto \phi(v)$. This identification should be used.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Sorry, I wrote down all definitions but still don't know how I use this map. I know it is linear and injective, in order to prove the equality I just need to show that his "restriction" to $\ker(T)\to (\text{Im}(T^*))^0$ is also surjective?